# Using a model declaration in a different view in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm Developing an application where a user can be "sign in" only with his email and later complete the registration providing a password.

I have the next views:

> +views
>
> --invitations
>
> --layouts
>
> --products
>
> --users

I want to implement a table where I will put the invitations and other table with the full registered users.

I'm having troubles to use the invitation model in another view (tour view).

```
<%= form_for @invitations, remote:true do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :email, class:'weight-700'%>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control',name:'email', placeholder:'email' %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :code_digest, :value => random_code %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

That code gives me this error:
`First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

I don't want to use `Invitation.new`because i have reader that it's not a good practice to do that.

And I don't know how to link the form with the creation of a new invitation without changing or refreshing the page. I know is something with routes and javascript, but I don't know how to proceed.

I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: "I don't want to use Invitation.new because i have reader that it's not a good practice to do that." - don't believe everything you read...

Comment: Additionally you should generate the random token in the model or controller - not in the view. You don't need to pass it through the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `@invitations` from the controller action where this form is rendered..

Suppose it's new, then

```
def new
  ...
  @invitations = Invitation.new
end
```